# How to apply ranged lookup on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe

```
Name   X 
Jack   2
Ann    4
John   18
```

and the following lookup table

```
X_Min X_Max Y
      2     2
3     7     4
8     15    9
16          25
```

Which `X_Min` and `X_Max` is the range of lookup value X in the first dataframe. I would like to apply the lookup table to my dataframe to have the result below

```
Name   X    Y(Targeted)
Jack   2    2
Ann    4    4
John   18   25
```

Thank you very much

Comment: There is mising value for `X_max` for last value?

Comment: It is intended, which means anything >= 16. I also removed the X_Min of the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`IntervalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) with replace first not defined value to `-inf` in `X_Min` and last `X_Max` missing value for `np.inf`:

```
print (df2)
   X_Min  X_Max   Y
0    NaN    2.0   2
1    3.0    7.0   4
2    8.0   15.0   9
3   16.0    NaN  25


i = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['X_Min'].fillna(-np.inf), 
                                 df2['X_Max'].fillna(np.inf), 'both')
print (i)
IntervalIndex([[-inf, 2.0], [3.0, 7.0], [8.0, 15.0], [16.0, inf]],
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

So possible filter values with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1['Y(Targeted)'] = df2.set_index(i).loc[df1['X'], 'Y'].values
print (df1)

   Name   X  Y(Targeted)
0  Jack   2            2
1   Ann   4            4
2  John  18           25
```

EDIT:

If want working only with `X_Max` column:

```
i = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['X_Max'].add(1).shift().fillna(-np.inf), 
                                 df2['X_Max'].fillna(np.inf), 'both')
print (i)
IntervalIndex([[-inf, 2.0], [3.0, 7.0], [8.0, 15.0], [16.0, inf]],
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

Comment: Thank you very very much

Comment: Just one more question, is it possible to eliminate the X_Min as it is equal to the X_Max of the previous row